# How is Django CSS is not getting picked up?

Tags: css, django

settings.py

```
    STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['guide/static/css', 'guide/static/js', ]
```

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}

...

<link href="{% static bootstrap.css %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static flexslider.css %}" type="text/css" media="screen" Department="" />
<link href="{% static services.css %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link href="{% static ziehharmonika.css %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{% static JiSlider.css %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static style.css %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- font-awesome icons -->
<link href="{% static font_awesome.css %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

Here is the project structure:

```
guide
- guide
- guideapp
- templates
    - base.html
    - index.html
- static
    - css
    - js
    - fonts
- db.sqlite3
- manage.py
```

Here, index extends base.html. The content shows up, but the css does not.

Comment: are you running this on the localenv and do you have debug = True

Comment: Yes, debug = true, and it's on the localenv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your settings.py file:

[image]

The STATICFILES_DIRS tuple tells Django where to look for static files that are not tied to a particular app. In this case, we just told Django to also look for static files in a folder called static in our root folder, not just in our apps.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your `bootstrap.css` is in the css directory. Can you try changing to

```
{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}
```

Or you can try giving full path with respect to your project. e.g `/static/css/bootstrap.css`

Comment: This was what I had tried previously. It throws an Exception: TemplateSyntaxError at /

Could not parse the remainder: '/bootstrap.css' from 'css/bootstrap.css'

Comment: Here is a snippet from my app: `{% load staticfiles i18n %}`

`{% block extrastyle %}`
    `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/APP/css/APP.css"/>`
    `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/angular-tablesort/css/angular-tablesort.css">`
`{% endblock %}`
The first href pointing to css in another app, while the second href is pointing to css while is common to the entire project.

Comment: Thank you. How did your settings.py configuration for the static files look like, if I may? And the project tree structure?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. Still learning to use stackoverflow formatting.
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
`STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/static'`

Sometimes I also need to reload the static files: python manage.py collectstatic

I usually rename the dir which contains settings.py to conf.

So my project tree be like,

Project /

    manage.py

    conf /

            settings.py (along with wsgi or other conf files)

    static /

            css/ js/ 

    templates /

          index.html    

    app1/

        static/ templates/ migration/ rest/ views/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'guide/static'),
)

<link href="{% static css/bootstrap.css %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

for js

{% static js/file.js %}
```

also one way to debug is entering the path `localhost:8000/static/css/file.css`